# How to check args starts with "--" in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

The following `bash` script can't check if the variable starts with "`--`" or not.

**Here is the test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Args: [$@]"

if [[ "${$@:0:2}" == "--" ]]
then
    echo -e "Args starts with --: [$@]"
else
    echo -e "Args does not start with --: [$@]"
fi
```

**Here is the test:**

```
./test.sh "--hello --many --args --here --must --starts --with"
./test.sh "world"
```

**Here is the output:**

```
root@test:~# ./test.sh "--hello"
Args: [--hello --many --args --here --must --starts --with]
./test.sh: line 5: ${$@:0:2}: bad substitution
root@test:~# ./test.sh "world"
Args: [world]
./test.sh: line 5: ${$@:0:2}: bad substitution
root@test:~#
```

What's the problem in the above script and how to fix?

Comment: `check args` which "arg"? First one? Second one? Any of them?

Comment: I mean to check `all args'. The first arg must starts with "--" when passing into the ./test.sh script. I don't want to allow the args without "--" to pass into the script. For example, `./test.sh "world --second-args"` is not allowed.

Comment: The above script sets "all args" as a variable, and then check if the variable starts with "--", it only checks the first arg in this script. But this script doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `./test.sh "world --second-args"` has __one__ argument, not two. Do you understand the difference between `./test.sh "world --second-args"` and `./test.sh world --second-args`? Do you want to check if any word inside the first argument starts with `--` or do you want to check if any argument starts with `--`? Arguments may contain spaces "inside" them.

Comment: You can't check all of the arguments all at once, like you seem to be trying to do. You need to check them one-by-one (probably by looping over them).

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. `./test.sh "--hello --many --args --here --must --starts --with"` calls your script with one single argument, not many. Maybe `if [[ "$1" = --* ]] ...`

Comment: You can not use `:0:2` on arrays. This is to extract a substring from a single variable. Also it is not clear from your question, what output you would expect from your test case.

Comment: The conventional way to implement command line arguments in Bash is via a `case` block. If you do that there will be no need to extract the first two characters to test if they are double dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${$@}` is invalid (same as `${$x}`) and should be `${@}`; but I don't think it makes sense to take a substring from this special (array?) variable.

---

Instead, you can use a loop and case statement to check positional parameters for a pattern. This will even work with `sh` and not only `bash`.

```
#!/bin/sh
for param; do
  echo "Checking positional parameter '$param'"
  case "$param" in
    --*) echo "Param '$param' starts with double-hyphen"
    ;;
    *) echo "Param '$param' does not start with double-hyphen"
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh "--hello --many --args --here --must --starts --with";
Checking positional parameter '--hello --many --args --here --must --starts --with'
Param '--hello --many --args --here --must --starts --with' starts with double-hyphen

$ ./test.sh "world"
Checking positional parameter 'world'
Param 'world' does not start with double-hyphen

$ ./test.sh -a -n 5 --verbose
Checking positional parameter '-a'
Param '-a' does not start with double-hyphen
Checking positional parameter '-n'
Param '-n' does not start with double-hyphen
Checking positional parameter '5'
Param '5' does not start with double-hyphen
Checking positional parameter '--verbose'
Param '--verbose' starts with double-hyphen

$ ./test.sh '-a -n 5 --verbose'
Checking positional parameter '-a -n 5 --verbose'
Param '-a -n 5 --verbose' does not start with double-hyphen
```

NB Quoted parameters count as a single parameter. If you require multiple separate parameters, you must not quote them.